# T-SQL Date Format with Substring

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, substring

We have a field by name target_date. It's a string. We need to extract the month and year from that field.

Example:
1/10/2011(dd/mm/yyyy)
we are trying with

```
 substring(target date,findstring(targetdate,"/",1)+1,(findstring(targetdate,"/",2)-findstring(targetdate,"/",1)+1)).
```

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Well, first issue here is that you are storing datetime as string. I will assume that for whatever reason you can't fix that...

What I would do in this case is use `convert()` function

```
convert(datetime, target_date, 103)
```

and then extract needed values using `month()` and `year()`

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

1. Use [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) to convert your string to datetime.
2. Use [DATEPART (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract month and year.

#### Sample

```
    -- this will give you the month of your target_date
    datePart(mm, convert(datetime, target_date, 103)) 

    -- this will give you the year of your target_date
    datePart(yyyy, convert(datetime, target_date, 103)) -- 2011
    -- or
    datePart(yy, convert(datetime, target_date, 103)) -- 11
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare @date varchar(10)

set @date = '1/10/2011'

select DATEPART(yyyy, CONVERT(datetime, @date, 103)), DATEPART(mm, CONVERT(datetime, @date, 103))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Month : left(right(target_date , 7),2)
Year: right(target_date , 4)
```

This is if the format of target_date is always the same (ie. dd/mm/yyyy)